# Why does tab_df() not print the whole table?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, sjplot

Thanks in advance.
Basically, I've produced a table and now I just want to print that onto a word document. For some reason however, when I do so it removes all the variables from the table. Could someone pls help me out?

the first line of code is what produced the Rmarkdown table, the second is the one that printed it onto a word document.

```
Table_1c <- knitr::kable(Table_1b, digits = 3, caption = "Table 1. Descriptive Statistics")

tab_df(Table_1b, title = "Table 1. Descriptive Statistics", file = "Table_1c.doc")
```

Comment: I think you'll have to make this a reproducible question because I don't have any problems with this function in and of itself. It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make all of your questions reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput(head(dataObject)))` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

The `file` option in the `tab_df` function allows to save the table as image in a HTML file. I will show you an example.

First the data sample as example:

```
# DATA
Table_1b <- iris[1:5,]
Table_1b
```

Output:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Next load package and set working directory to store the table as html file:

```
library(sjPlot)
# Set working directory
setwd("~/Downloads")
tab_df(Table_1b, title = "Table 1. Descriptive Statistics", file = "Table_1c.html")
```

With this as output:
[image]